# How to use ExtractAssociatedIcon in dartlang win32 package

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, pointers, winapi

I am building a flutter desktop app for demo purpose.

One of my ideas is showing associated icon of a executable file. Just like you see in OS explorer.

By now I cannot find a flutter pack which helps me meet this need cross Linus, MacOS and Windows. Then I turned to win32 package which contains a function called ExtractAssociatedIcon. The same name I used with C# decades ago.

Here is definition of this function in shell32.g.dart file.

```dart
int ExtractAssociatedIcon(int hInst, Pointer<Utf16> pszIconPath, Pointer<Uint16> piIcon)
```

I use ***GetModuleHandle(nullptr)*** for hInst parameter. ***fileFullPath.toNativeUtf16()*** for pszIconPath. But I cannot figure out what is for piIcon.

I know piIcon is index of the icon. But the parameter type is ***Pointer***. I don't know how to convert integer 0 to this type.

I know ***Pointer.fromAddress*** constructor. But takes address. Not a value.

Can anyone help that would be much appreciated.

I like to know how to call ***int ExtractAssociatedIcon(int hInst, Pointer pszIconPath, Pointer piIcon)*** in dartlang.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extractassociatediconw) explains what `piIcon` is (a pointer to a 16-bit signed integer value).

Comment: Mr. IInspectable pointed to the correct official documentation. You can define a `WORD pIcon`, Put `&pIcon` in the third parameter of the function.